# Logging object to cloud run with zerolog with Go

Tags: object, logging, google-cloud-run

My service in google cloud run tries to log a struct with zerolog. The entry does not show in the stackdriver log. It works properly when I test it on my local machine outside the cloud run environment.

This is the code, req is a go struct:

```
import "github.com/rs/zerolog/log"

log.Info().
    Int("nprocs", prober.NProcs).
    Int("timeout", prober.Timeout).
    Int("dial_timeout", prober.DialTimeout).
    Interface("probe_request", &req).
    Msg("received request")
```

The "probe_request" field is missing in the jsonPayload in the Stack Driver log.

Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Can you have more piece of code to reproduce your case? Does this log work locally?

Comment: Hi Guillaume, I have found the cause of my problem. The cloud run traffic was not automatically directed to the new version of the service, so I was looking at the old one. All's well now.

Cheers